# Edit Cookie HttpOnly value

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

Due to PCI regulations, most cookies in my application need to be secure and httponly. I have achieved that through this line in my Apache config file:

Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure

However this breaks part of the application where a single cookie, let's call it foobar, must be read by javascript. Therefore I need to remove the httponly for this cookie only.

I've played around with several approaches including mod_rewrite but I can't get the httponly to drop off the cookie. I don't want to reset the value of the cookie etc, just take off the httponly part.

E.g. Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(foobar=.*)$ $1
(doesn't work)

Comment: What is the apache version?

Comment: 2.4.23. I'll try your answer now and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^((?!foobar=).*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

Comment: When I tried this, none of the cookies get HttpOnly or Secure added. I guess it didn't like the regex?

Comment: Indeed it was off the top of my head, but I did expect it to work. I'll try to test and see what's wrong.

Comment: Try the modified directive please (`always` removed, and modified regex)

Comment: It also works with "always". So it may have been a bad regex before.

Comment: @Ivan where do we need to add the above code?

Comment: in your Apache config file

Comment: If you need to conditionally modify the content of 'Set-Cookie' header, you might also be interested by this proposed solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76623121/10001863