# How to solve `SameSite` attribute

Tags: php, html

I looked at the console and noticed these warnings

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the SameSite attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite=None and Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

How to solve it?

Comment: https://medium.com/@PeterNagyJob/how-did-i-waste-6-hours-finding-out-all-about-same-site-cookies-82d75062ede2

Comment: Refer this : https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained

It probably has to do with your domain name and TLD.

Comment: @vS12 Would it add this at the beginning of my code? https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/php.md

Comment: I guess so, because it's set in the headers of the request.

Comment: Minor text edit for clarity

Comment: @vS12 I put at the beginning of the file, still the error continues :(

Comment: @Tiago - not an expert in php, check this answer - as they discuss on how to deal with this in php. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750906/php-setcookie-samesite-strict

Comment: Chrome is showing this error in the dev tools console in every web site I visit.

Comment: None of the answers will work unless the external resources that you use, are set with `SameSite=None` from their source. This can only be added by the developers of those resources with access to the code or server that their cookies are being set from. See: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/issues/4#issuecomment-548598318

Answer (score 11):

A solution that worked for me:

**If you are using PHP,** add this line to the beginning

```
header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=name; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

---

**Update**
Here is a useful resource including examples in JavaScript, Node.js, PHP, and Python
https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples

Comment: Still continues. I put the code at the beginning of the index.php file and still the errors continue.

Comment: This will not work for external resources that have not altered their setting of cookies. See https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/issues/4#issuecomment-548598318

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing you can do until Google's developers/admins (and developers/admins of other external resources) modify their scripts/servers to include the necessary cookies settings to the cookies they generate when your website includes them. See here more more info:

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/issues/4#issuecomment-548598318

If you are debugging your website, you can temporarily ignore those entries in Chrome's developer tools console by adding this filter to the filter box:

`-SameSite=None`

For example:

[image: Example of -SameSite=None filter in Chrome's developer tools console]

Answer (score 1):

Does your .htaccess file contain a header unset cookie code? and you use cdn and its cache like cloudflare.

If so, just delete the code in the htaccess

Comment: Hello, I do not use cloudflare. What can it be?

Comment: I think this link is best answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129201/add-secure-and-httponly-flags-to-every-set-cookie-response-in-apache-httpd

Comment: See if I get it right. Inside my htacess I add this line `Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure"`?